# How to create a dropdown-menu full of links or `<a>` tags?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

### Details

- I want create a drop-down menu full of links or `<a>` tags
- When I clicked on them, will zoom in to the option that I clicked on.

### What I've tried

`PHP/HTML`

```
<div class="col-sm-6 drop-down ">
        Select Country : 
        <select id="state" name="state" class="select2" data-placeholder="Click to Choose...">
            <option value="">--Select--</option>
            <?php 
            foreach(array_unique($countries) as $country){ ?>
            <option href="#<?php echo $country ; ?>"  value="#<?php echo $country ; ?> "><a href="#<?php echo $country ; ?>" ><?php echo $country ; ?></a> </option>
            <?php } ?>  
        </select>
    </div>
```

### Issue

- When I click on it, it doesn't go anywhere at all
- It just stay there like nothing happen
- URL is not take effect also.

Comment: you can't embed html into an `<option>` like that. if you want to make them "clickable" as if they were links, then you'd have to add an `onclick` or `onchange` javascript handler to the parent `<select>` and do your redirection/linking there.

Comment: Listen to `change` event of the `HTMLSelectElement` object and change the `href` property of the `location` object.

Comment: I just added This `$("#state").change(function()
  {
   document.location.href = $(this).val();
  });` - the only diff is the URL. No Effect :(

Comment: Remove the select and it *might* work.

Comment: @Fred-ii- : You mean the `<select>` tag ?. I did that -  and it print out a list of countries.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the only diff is the URL"?

Comment: After I did the script, the only things that are different is the URL. Nothing else, seem to work. Let me double check my work again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a very simple solution you could do it like that:

```
<select onchange="window.location=this.value">
    <option value="">Select:</option>
    <option value="http://google.com">google</option>
    <option value="http://yahoo.com">yahoo</option>
</select>
```

In your case you should use window.location.hash instead of window.location

Comment: Nice I didn't know you can do inline `onchange`

Comment: When I click on it, It linked to it. It really hard to see, can you help me change the color of the `selected` country-name to red and when I click on it.

Comment: *"Nice I didn't know you can do inline onchange"* @evoque2015 Actually, that is one of the oldest methods used since the early days of JS and hyperlinking to URLs from dropdowns ;-)

Comment: I kind of like this one to be honest.

Comment: You could use CSS to color the selected option but I don't know if it works for all browsers:

<style>select option:checked {color:#ff0000;}</style>

Answer (score 2):

You cant have additional html in the links.

Instead use the anchors as the values for the options, and set then with javascript when a change is detected:

```
<select onchange="go(this.value);">
    <option value="#one">1</option>
    <option value="#two">2</option>
    <option value="#three">3</option>
</select>

<div id="one">one</div>
<div id="two">two</div>
<div id="three">three</div>

<script>
function go(link){
    window.location.hash = link;
}
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dcg5t097/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if an `<a>` tag is supposed to be inside an `<option>`, that's one thing. Your HTML looks like you're using bootstrap, so why don't you just use bootstraps dropdown-class? If you really want to use a `<select>` you probably need to use JavaScript, to listen to a change-Event and then scroll to the part you want.

The other thing is this:

Your link for, say Egypt, looks like this:

```
<a href="#Egypt" >Egypt</a>
```

while your according content looks something like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-2">
    <h5 id="#Africa" >Egypt</h5>
</div>
```

But for your link to work, you actually need something with the id specified in the `href` attribute, so you should change your code to this:

```
<div class="col-xs-2">
    <h5 id="Egypt" >Egypt</h5>
</div>
```